# What does Woolsey play at the end of Stargate Atlantis: Broken Ties?

Tags: stargate, stargate-atlantis, music-identification

What is the classical music played by Woolsey in his room at the end of the programme?

Comment: There is a thread about this [here](https://forum.gateworld.net/threads/67606-Broken-Ties-Classical-Music-At-The-End-Whats-Is-It).  Don't have a real answer, though.

Comment: The description of that very video says "It is an unreleased Music-Piece composed for the cast of Stargate by Joel Goldsmith."

Comment: Also, German Teyla :D

Comment: @DisturbedNeo - I couldn't find an English version :-) It's the same music though

Comment: No complaints from me, I like Teyla in any language :P

Comment: While looking for the music, I saw a "soundtrack" album for Atlantis (expensive and no idea if the music is on it).  @DisturbedNeo Also, there was a Rachel Luttrell (Teyla) album

Answer (score 7):

It's indeed a piece of music made for the show, and as far as I know, it doesn't have a name.

On his blog, Joseph Mallozzi, writer and producer of *Stargate Atlantis* (among others), wrote about "Broken Ties" just after the episode aired, and revealed that Joel Goldsmith composed that piece instead of picking up an existing one.

> THE FINAL MONTAGE: Teyla’s family/Bathtub McKay/Sheppard and Ronon.
>
> The third and final montage sequence of the episode. I gave Joel Goldsmith the choice of either finding an appropriate classical piece for this sequence or scoring it himself. **To no one’s surprise, he composed a beautiful piece to compliment the montage.**
>
> <sub>["July 26, 2008: The Broken Ties Breakdown", by Joseph Mallozzi](https://josephmallozzi.com/2008/07/26/june-26-2008-the-broken-ties-breakdown/)</sub>